# How to find the value of $\ \lim_{x\to 3^+}\frac{\sqrt{x^2-9}}{x-3}$?

Tags: calculus, limits, radicals

How do I find the value of this limit?

$$\lim_{x\to 3^+}\frac{\sqrt{x^2-9}}{x-3}$$

It says that it's approaching from right side to 3 right?

I tried subsitituting the 3 into the variables, and got 0, and the answer says that it's positive infinity.

I tried using those graphing software, I don't know how it's positive infinity.
I'm pretty sure there's something I'm doing wrong.

Comment: Substituting $3$ in for $x$ doesn't give $0$: it gives the form $0/0$ which is indeterminate.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We have
\begin{align}
\lim_{x\rightarrow 3^{+}}\frac{\sqrt{x^2-9}}{x-3}& =\lim_{x\rightarrow 3^{+}}\frac{\sqrt{\left(x+3\right)\left(x-3\right)}}{x-3}\tag{1} \\[1ex]
& = \lim_{x\rightarrow 3^{+}}\frac{\sqrt{\left(x+3\right)\left(x-3\right)}}{\sqrt{\left(x-3\right)^2}} \tag{2}\\[1ex]
& =\lim_{x\rightarrow 3^{+}}\sqrt{\frac{\left(x+3\right)}{\left(x-3\right)}} \tag{3}\\[1ex]
& = \lim_{x\rightarrow 3^{+}}\sqrt{1+\frac{6}{x-3}}\tag{4} \\[1ex]
& =\infty.\tag{5}
\end{align}
Here is a graph as well with gridlines at $x=-3,3$:

[image]

Notice that the function is undefined on $\mathbb{R}^2$ between $x\in\left[-3,3\right)$.

Comment: Can you explain me $+1$ in $(4)$?

Comment: @Tacet do some long division... you'll find that $$ \frac{x+3}{x-3} = 1+\frac{6}{x-3}. $$

Comment: Och, right! I was so blind, thank you. Nice answer. +1

Answer (score 3):

You should know, that
$$ \left(\forall a \in \mathbb{R}^{+}\right)(\lim_{x\to 0+}\frac{a}{x} = +\infty)$$

---

**Hint**:

$$\lim_{x\to3+}x-3 = \lim_{x\to0+}x$$

Carefully! You cannot directly considering! You haven't some number in nominator. You receive $\frac{0}{0}$ — it is [indeterminate form](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indeterminate_form).

**Hint2**: Shortcut formulas

$$ (x^2-9) = (x+3)(x-3)$$

**Hint3**:

$$ x-3 \geq 0 \Longrightarrow x-3 = \sqrt{(x-3)^2}$$

Answer (score 1):

Note that for $x > 3$, we have
$$\dfrac{\sqrt{x^2-9}}{x-3} = \sqrt{\dfrac{x+3}{x-3}}$$
Now look at what happens to the numerator and denominator as $x \to 3^+$.

Comment: Worth noting: That equality is only true if $x>3$, which is why the question is $x\to 3^+$.

Comment: Note that $x\neq 3$ is not enough here.

Comment: Maybe I'm being silly, but I think it's worth adding in the intermediate step in that rewriting.

Answer (score 0):

$$\lim_{x\to 3^+} \dfrac{\sqrt{x^2-9}}{x-3} = \lim_{x\to 3^+} \sqrt{\dfrac{x+3}{x-3}} 
= \lim_{x\to 3^+} \sqrt{\dfrac{6}{x-3}}  = +\infty
$$

Comment: $$\lim_{x\to 3^+} \dfrac{\sqrt{x^2-9}}{x-3} = \lim_{x\to 3^+} \frac{0}{x-3} = 0$$

Answer (score 0):

Its clearly +∞ try substituting x as 3+h where h tends to zero simplify and get the answer..